# Different values for Time.now when using activerecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this weird situation:

When I do on rails console `Time.now` or `Time.zone.now` I get the same values (suppose they run at the sime time: `2014-06-05 23:38:06 -0300`)

But when I use Time.now in a query like: `Match.where("datetime = ?", Time.now)` it returns the time 3 hours ahead!

.to_sql output:

```
SELECT `matches`.* FROM `matches`  WHERE (datetime = '2014-06-06 02:38:06')
```

any thoughts on that?

- Rails 4
- Mysql 5.5

Comment: how are the values stored in your database, local time or UTC?

Comment: Then the sql generated is correct. ActiveRecord is converting from local time to UTC before executing the statement on the database in order to be consistent with how the data is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time you are seeing in sql query is **UTC** time.  The reason you have `Time.now` and `Time.zone.now` return the same time in rails console is because you have both your system and your rails application in the same time zone.  It is `Time.now` that returns the system time based on the system time zone and `Time.zone.now` that returns the application's time zone aware time.

There are couple of options that can be set as far as the timezone used in the query is concerned, you can either set it to `:utc` which is the default or set it to `:local`.  You have `utc` configured and this is the default.  `:local` sets the timezone to server's time zone.  This setting is set in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
```

The second portion - rails application's time zone can also be set in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.time_zone = 'Brasilia'
```

With this setup, when you use time zone aware classes e.g. `Time.zone.now` to retrieve time in your application they will be using this configured timezone.  Also a point to note with the setting `config.time_zone` would be to use timezone aware classes in your application to ensure consistent translation of time zone regardless of environment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Set default_timezone to :local in config/application.rb worked fine and Is the best solution in my current scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the same times.  One has a UTC offset of -3, the other is in UTC time and doesn't have the offset.